# Is healing with honey mentioned in the Koran?

Tags: quran, health

From [webmd](http://www.webmd.com/vitamins-supplements/ingredientmono-738-honey.aspx?activeingredientid=738)

> Honey’s healing properties are mentioned in the [..] Koran [..].

Is this true? What does the Quran say about honey's healing properties?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the Qur'an does refer to the healing properties of honey:

> وَأَوْحَىٰ رَبُّكَ إِلَى النَّحْلِ أَنِ اتَّخِذِي مِنَ الْجِبَالِ بُيُوتًا وَمِنَ الشَّجَرِ وَمِمَّا يَعْرِشُونَ ۝ ثُمَّ كُلِي مِن كُلِّ الثَّمَرَاتِ فَاسْلُكِي سُبُلَ رَبِّكِ ذُلُلًا ۚ يَخْرُجُ مِن بُطُونِهَا شَرَابٌ مُّخْتَلِفٌ أَلْوَانُهُ فِيهِ شِفَاءٌ لِّلنَّاسِ ۗ إِنَّ فِي ذَٰلِكَ لَآيَةً لِّقَوْمٍ يَتَفَكَّرُونَ
>
> And your Lord inspired to the bee, "Take for yourself among the mountains, houses, and among the trees and [in] that which they construct. ۝ Then eat from all the fruits and follow the ways of your Lord laid down [for you]." There emerges from their bellies a drink, varying in colors, in which there is healing for people. Indeed in that is a sign for a people who give thought.
>
> <sup>— [Surat An-Nahl 16:68-69](https://quran.com/16/68-69/)</sup>

It is to be noted that the verses refer to real honey from bees that are free to roam around **following the ways of their Lord**, and **eating from all the fruits** as they will ... not from bees that are farmed and fed according to controlled programs, then have their honey processed to produce the products one buys in today's markets.

The Prophet ﷺ emphasized the same concept in his hadith:

> حَدَّثَنِي الْحُسَيْنُ، حَدَّثَنَا أَحْمَدُ بْنُ مَنِيعٍ، حَدَّثَنَا مَرْوَانُ بْنُ شُجَاعٍ، حَدَّثَنَا سَالِمٌ الأَفْطَسُ، عَنْ سَعِيدِ بْنِ جُبَيْرٍ، عَنِ ابْنِ عَبَّاسٍ ـ رضى الله عنهما ـ قَالَ ‏ "‏ الشِّفَاءُ فِي ثَلاَثَةٍ شَرْبَةِ عَسَلٍ، وَشَرْطَةِ مِحْجَمٍ، وَكَيَّةِ نَارٍ، وَأَنْهَى أُمَّتِي عَنِ الْكَىِّ ‏"‏‏.‏ رَفَعَ الْحَدِيثَ وَرَوَاهُ الْقُمِّيُّ عَنْ لَيْثٍ عَنْ مُجَاهِدٍ عَنِ ابْنِ عَبَّاسٍ عَنِ النَّبِيِّ صلى الله عليه وسلم فِي الْعَسَلِ وَالْحَجْمِ‏.‏
>
> Narrated by Ibn 'Abbas that the Prophet (ﷺ) said: "Healing is in three things: A gulp of honey, cupping, and branding with fire (cauterizing). But I forbid my followers to use (cauterization) branding with fire."
>
> <sup>— [Sahih al-Bukhari 5680](https://www.sunnah.com/bukhari/76/3)</sup>

This was put into practice: honey was used to cure bowel movement during the time of the Prophet ﷺ as can be seen from this hadith:

> حَدَّثَنَا مُحَمَّدُ بْنُ الْمُثَنَّى، وَمُحَمَّدُ بْنُ بَشَّارٍ، - وَاللَّفْظُ لاِبْنِ الْمُثَنَّى - قَالاَ حَدَّثَنَا مُحَمَّدُ بْنُ جَعْفَرٍ، حَدَّثَنَا شُعْبَةُ، عَنْ قَتَادَةَ، عَنْ أَبِي الْمُتَوَكِّلِ، عَنْ أَبِي سَعِيدٍ الْخُدْرِيِّ، قَالَ جَاءَ رَجُلٌ إِلَى النَّبِيِّ صلى الله عليه وسلم فَقَالَ إِنَّ أَخِي اسْتَطْلَقَ بَطْنُهُ ‏.‏ فَقَالَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏"‏ اسْقِهِ عَسَلاً ‏"‏ ‏.‏ فَسَقَاهُ ثُمَّ جَاءَهُ فَقَالَ إِنِّي سَقَيْتُهُ عَسَلاً فَلَمْ يَزِدْهُ إِلاَّ اسْتِطْلاَقًا ‏.‏ فَقَالَ لَهُ ثَلاَثَ مَرَّاتٍ ثُمَّ جَاءَ الرَّابِعَةَ فَقَالَ ‏"‏ اسْقِهِ عَسَلاً ‏"‏ ‏.‏ فَقَالَ لَقَدْ سَقَيْتُهُ فَلَمْ يَزِدْهُ إِلاَّ اسْتِطْلاَقًا ‏.‏ فَقَالَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏"‏ صَدَقَ اللَّهُ وَكَذَبَ بَطْنُ أَخِيكَ ‏"‏ ‏.‏ فَسَقَاهُ فَبَرَأَ ‏.‏
>
> Abu Sa'id Khudri reported that a person came to Allah's Apostle (ﷺ) and told him that his brother's bowels were loose. Thereupon Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said: Give him honey. So he gave him that and then came and said: I gave him honey but it has only made his bowels looser. He said this three times; then he came the fourth time, and he (the Holy Prophet) said: Give him honey. He said: I did give him, but it has only made his bowels looser, whereupon Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said: Allah has spoken the truth and your brother's bowels are in the wrong. So he made him drink (honey) and he was recovered.
>
> <sup>— [Sahih Muslim 2217 a](https://www.sunnah.com/muslim/39/122)</sup>

It is worth noting that some scholarly opinions are that the healing properties mentioned in the verse are those of the Qur'an, not of the honey. This opinion is also possible, in spite of the [hadith in Sunan Ibn Majah](https://www.sunnah.com/urn/1335790) about healing with both honey and the Qur'an, as it is a weak hadith.